# Having trouble running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

So I am trying to learn how to write tests, as I will be having to do them at work soon.

I was following the guide from here: http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html

and was trying to run this command, which was probably a quarter of the way down the page

```
rspec spec/models/contact_spec.rb
```

So i first ran into this problem on a very large app at work, ran into issues. So i decided to follow the steps from a smaller app i was working on. Still ran into issues. So I finally created a brand new app, (just basically did a 'rails new' and tinkered with the gem files). With this essentially blank rails app, i again went through the tutorial that i was reading, and again when i got to that command, ran into issues.

The error that I get is: (followed by about 10 lines of gem file errors which i don't think need to be listed)

```
/Users/kdweber89/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/kdweber89/Desktop/railspractice/rspecTesting/spec/models/spec/models/contact_spec.rb (LoadError)
```

I really have no idea what i am doing wrong with this, especially since i have followed the tutorial as best as i can.

Could anybody take a quick look at this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully at the path in your error message:

```
spec/models/spec/models/contact_spec.rb
```

Notice that `spec/models` is repeated? That's probably because you're running this command from within the `spec/models` directory, rather than the project root.